# Failed to configure a DataSource from command line

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to change Datasource setting from command Line. I have a application.properties with default setting. I would like to modify the parameters in the file from command Line, but when I pass Datasource arguments , I receive an error. I read on Externalized Configuration document :"Accessing Command Line Properties
By default, SpringApplication converts any command line option arguments (that is, arguments starting with --, such as --server.port=9000) to a property and adds them to the Spring Environment. As mentioned previously, command line properties always take precedence over other property sources".
I supposed that arguments overwrite the default setting into application.properties, but I'm missng some steps about that.

I've tried without spring.datasource.url or Placeholders in Properties. Below application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.url =  jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:port:DB11G
#spring.datasource.url = ${spring.datasource.url}
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.username = dbUser
spring.datasource.password = password
```

My application with datasource default settings run well.

this is my code:

```
spring.datasource.url = ${db.url}
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.username = dbUser
spring.datasource.password = dbPassword
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class IdsFeApplication implements ApplicationRunner{



    private static final String FEC_CODEX = "A";

    @Autowired
    private static ConfigInfoDB infoDb;

    @Autowired
    private Login fec;






      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            SpringApplication bootApp = new SpringApplication(IdsFeApplication.class);
            bootApp.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
            bootApp.setLogStartupInfo(false);
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context = bootApp.run(args);
            ConfigInfoDB db=context.getBean(ConfigInfoDB.class);
            db.dbInfo();


    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        fec.token(FEC_CODEX);


    }

}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured". When I pass argument from command line. if I do not pass anything and leave only the default information in the application.properties file the application works correctly. What I can not understand and how do I go from the command line to the database configuration information and make them priority over those contained in the application.properties file

Comment: Priorities work as described in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html  You haven't specified how you are passing the URL in command line, so I presume that is the problem.

Comment: Into STS, I pass the URL in Run Configuration - Arguments - Program Arguments and in the Text Area I write : --spring.datasource.url =  jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:port:DB11G. I read the document and tried some different external configuration but can't understant how it works the right configuration.

Comment: spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:port:DB11G. This statement is exactle the same I wrote into application.properties. If I use the default configuration my app runs well.

Comment: Can you try it without spaces? `--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:port:DB11G`

Comment: I've tried but I've the same error:"***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class"

Comment: Can you instead try to pass it as a system property? So a VM argument instead of a command line argument with `-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:port:DB11G`

Comment: Alternatively try using your own placeholder in your `applications.properties`: `spring.datasource.url=${db.url}` and then pass it to the command line arguments without any spaces `--db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:port:DB11G` I have an application that works exactly like this that I just tested, it should definitely work. If not you have something else wrong.

Comment: I've already tried your solution before, but it didn't work. Anyway Above I put my code, maybe you could see where I have something else wrong.

Comment: Mmm not sure at this point, but can you try doing these please? Change the top annotation to `@SpringBootApplication`. (I would also put your `ApplicationRunner` to a separate class annotated by `@Component`. Just in case it is somehow interfereing with the command line arguments which are passed to `run()`, try to disable it for a test to see if it is the cause)

Comment: only changed SpringBootConfiguration in SpringBootApplication and It's started to work...Excellent. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciated your support to get a solution.

Comment: OK glad it worked. Can you mark the answer so that other people can easily see what was the problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your top annotation from `@SpringBootConfiguration` to `@SpringBootApplication`.

`@SpringBootApplication` in reality is a shortcut for `@configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` does a lot of the magic behind the scenes of configuring your application based on what dependencies are included and what information it finds in the environment.